# How are the top items calculated?

Tags: statistics

Imagine a list of items e.g. books. How do you determine which books are the most popular/best? So for example, you would put a book rated 4.7 on average with 100 ratings, higher than a book rated 4.9 on average with 10 ratings. What is the formula for that?

Comment: Maybe off-topic comment : But "most popular" and "best" is not necessarily the same.

Comment: You might be nterested in reading about "empirical Bayes estimation", e.g. http://varianceexplained.org/r/empirical_bayes_baseball/

Answer (score 0):

Use a weighted score mechanism, weighted against the amount of ratings. For example:

$$ \frac{average\space rating\space of\space book \times number\space of\space ratings\space per\space book}{number\space of\space total\space ratings} $$